# How to see if you're clicking the same element twice? Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, this

How can you detect if the user is clicking the same div?

I've tried this with no success:

```
    _oldthis = null;

    var _this = $(this);

    if(_oldthis == _this) {
        alert('You clicked this last');
    }

    _oldthis = _this;
```

Comment: had you declare _oldthis

Comment: I think you need to provide some more context... do oyu need to store a history of clicks and compare against it somewhere? if so, for what reason? Also if you could psot the full click handler instead of jsut an excerpt of its code that would be useful :-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't compare jQuery objects, but you can compare the DOM objects they contain. Try this:

```
var previousTarget=null;
$("a").click(function() {
    if(this===previousTarget) {
        alert("You've clicked this element twice.");
    }
    previousTarget=this;
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Note that it is important to use "this" and not "$(this)"

Comment: @TaylorMac what does the return false do?

Comment: @user2763557: Here I was assuming that the link was something like `<a href="#">...</a>`, where the default action of the browser would be to go to `#` (often jumping to the top of the page), which I was imagining would be undesirable in this case. `return false` prevents the default browser behavior. If the default behavior is fine and you don't want to prevent it, you don't need to `return false`.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this,

```
var _oldthis = null;
$('div').click(function(){
  var _this = $(this);

  if(_this == _oldthis) {
    alert('You clicked this last');
    _oldthis = null;
    return false;
  }
  _oldthis = _this;
```

});

Answer (score 0):

```
var clickHandler;
$('a').click(function(){
    if(clickHandler) {
        clickHandler = alert('click twice');
    } else {
        clickHandler = alert('click once');
    }
});
```