# jQuery Tabs, revert to default tab after second click

Tags: jquery, tabs, click

I have a jQuery tab code that works as expected. 
However now I'm trying to add some functionality. If a tab navigation link is clicked, it should do its default action, which is to open the tab.

If the same tab navigation link is clicked again, the tab that just opened should close, and it should revert back to the originally opened tab.

I've tried to add the code from [this snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/7YATm/) to my own tab code. But I can't get it to work. However there are no errors in the console.

Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

EDIT: Oke, I've played around a lot with it. Reasoning that everything that gets added after the first click, should be removed as well if I want to restore the default tab. I can get it to show/hide a tab on every second click now (probably in the most inefficient way ever, but it kinda works).

However it also 'works' when going from one tab navigation link, to the other. As opposed to only doing it after the same element is clicked twice. I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NK78/V4QZ2/7/), but for some reason the tabs won't even work there. Don't know if I need to tick any other boxes in the fiddle (it's my first fiddle :))

EDIT2

I figured it out thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688561/how-to-see-if-youre-clicking-the-same-element-twice-jquery).

Working code:

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

  $(".tab_content:not(:first)").addClass("hide").hide();
  $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show();

  var previousTarget=null;
  $("a.tabsclic").click(function() {
  if(this===previousTarget) {
             $(".tab_content:not(:first)").addClass("hide").hide();
             $(".tab_content:first").removeClass("hide").show();
             $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show();
             var $this = $(this).attr('href');
             $("ul.tabs li >     a.tabsclic[href=" + $this + "]").parent().removeClass("active");
             previousTarget=null;
             return false;
  }
        previousTarget=this;
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        });
        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
        $("#topics-fav a").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass('active');
        var $this = $(this).attr('href');
        $("ul.tabs li >     a.tabsclic[href=" + $this + "]").parent().addClass("active");
        $(".tab_content").addClass("hide").hide();
        var activeTab = jQuery($this);
        if ($.browser.msie) {
            $(activeTab).show();
        } else {
            $(activeTab).fadeIn();
        } return false;
   });
});
```

Comment: please make a jsfiddle for this

Comment: remove the `return false` or put it in the end

Comment: I've updated it with an edit. Having some trouble with the jsfiddle.

Comment: Oke, I've figured it out. It works. I'll update the question with the working code.