# Expand a div in a grid after each row jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this, actually i want to make something like google images function, i mean if i click the wherever li, the expanded div is always below the row that containing li that i've clicked, anny suggestion ? Thanks

FIDDLE [>>](http://jsfiddle.net/3a7pjeb9/13/)

```
<div class="container">
    <ul>  
      <li>
       <a href="#"><img src="http://s13.postimg.org/8caamw1af/image4.jpg" /></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#"><img src="http://s13.postimg.org/8caamw1af/image4.jpg" /></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#"><img src="http://s13.postimg.org/8caamw1af/image4.jpg" /></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#"><img src="http://s13.postimg.org/8caamw1af/image4.jpg" /></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#"><img src="http://s13.postimg.org/8caamw1af/image4.jpg" /></a>
      </li>

     <li class="expanded">
     <div>abc</div>
     </li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

    $( ".container ul li" ).click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var idNum = id.split('-');
        var num = parseInt(idNum[1]);
        var a = Math.ceil(num/4)*4;

        //alert(a);

        $('.container ul li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('.container ul li li.expanded').slideUp(400,function(){
            $(this).insertAfter($('.container ul li #item-'+a)).slideDown(400);
        })
    }); 
});
```

**CSS**

```
body, ul {   
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;  
}
.container {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
li {
    width: 23%;
    margin: 10px 1% 0 1%;
    float: left;
    list-style: none outside none;

}
li img {
    width: 100%;
}

.expanded {
    position: relative;   
    display: none;
    background: #ccc;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear!! Can you be more specific??

Comment: Is there just one expanded div?

Comment: do you need similar to this http://codepen.io/gabrieleromanato/pen/dDyzH?

Comment: i've edited the question @guruprasad-rao , yes one div only

Comment: i'll update that 1 from ajax then @nevermind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want the expanded element to behave as follows:

- Show if an li is clicked.
- Hide when the *same* li is clicked.
- Hide first then show again if it is visible and a *different* li is clicked.

There are many ways to achieve this.

One relatively simple approach would be to differentiate your li elements so you can identify which specific li was clicked. This can be a done in a number of ways, but in your case you could simply add a unique id to each li.
I have used numbers here for demonstration purposes - you may want to be a bit more descriptive in your code.

Next you need to modify your javascript to check which li was clicked. You can use your "expanded" variable to keep track of which li last activated the expanded element. (we can regard 0 as its inactive state)

So on each click you check if the clicked li previously toggled the expanded element. If it did, then simply close the element. if it didn't then close the element and re-open it using a callback function.

I hope this answers your question.

**EDIT: The below snippet has been revised to move the expanded element to its clicked li's row. This will only work if there are 4 images per row.**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
    var expanded = 0;

    $( ".container ul li" ).click(function(e) {
      
      e.preventDefault();
         
      var clicked = $(this).attr("id");
                   
      if (clicked == expanded){
        $( ".expanded" ).slideUp("slow", function(){
            $(".expanded").remove();
            expanded = 0;
          });      
      }else if (expanded == 0){
        $(".container ul #"+Math.ceil(clicked/4)*4).after('<li class="expanded"><div>abc</div></li>');
        $( ".expanded" ).slideDown("slow");
        expanded = clicked;
      }else{
        $( ".expanded" ).slideUp("slow", function(){
          $(".expanded").remove();
          $(".container ul #"+Math.ceil(clicked/4)*4).after('<li class="expanded"><div>abc</div></li>');
          $( ".expanded" ).slideDown("slow", function(){      
            expanded = clicked;
          });      
        });
      }   
    }); 

    });
```

```css
body, ul {   
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;  
    height:1000px;
   }
   .container {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
   }
   li {
    width: 23%;
    margin: 10px 1% 0 1%;
    float: left;
    list-style: none outside none;

   }
   li img {
    width: 100%;
   }

   .expanded {
    position: relative;   
    display: none;
    background: #ccc;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <ul>  
      <li id="1">
       <a href="#"><img src="http://s13.postimg.org/8caamw1af/image4.jpg" /></a>
      </li>
      <li id="2">
       <a href="#"><img src="http://s13.postimg.org/8caamw1af/image4.jpg" /></a>
      </li>
      <li id="3">
       <a href="#"><img src="http://s13.postimg.org/8caamw1af/image4.jpg" /></a>
      </li>
      <li id="4">
       <a href="#"><img src="http://s13.postimg.org/8caamw1af/image4.jpg" /></a>
      </li>
      <li id="5">
       <a href="#"><img src="http://s13.postimg.org/8caamw1af/image4.jpg" /></a>
      </li>
      <li id="6">
       <a href="#"><img src="http://s13.postimg.org/8caamw1af/image4.jpg" /></a>
      </li>
      <li id="7">
       <a href="#"><img src="http://s13.postimg.org/8caamw1af/image4.jpg" /></a>
      </li>
      <li id="8">
       <a href="#"><img src="http://s13.postimg.org/8caamw1af/image4.jpg" /></a>
      </li>
            

     

    </ul>
   </div>
```

Comment: $(this).insertAfter($('.container ul li #item-'+a)).slideDown(400); @peter-ringelmann

Comment: I think I misunderstood your original question :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3a7pjeb9/13/ @peter-ringelmann like google images result function

Comment: @Sandra.G please see my revised snippet.

Comment: Can i add if  Math.ceil(clicked/4)*4) = more than 4 it will do like $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 485}, 500); @peter-ringelmann

Comment: @Sandra.G Yes you could do something like that. I have added "e.preventDefault();" to my snippet as the <a> tags make the page scroll to the top on each click. (you could probably remove the <a> tags as they don't seem to be performing any kind of function at the moment) You will also have to experiment with the page layout in terms of how you adjust the scroll height on each click to fit the expanded element into view. This is up to you to solve - good luck :)

Comment: I think iface a bug on the last li, when click, its not open, and then the other li can't be clicked too @peter-ringelmann

Answer (score 0):

**li.after($( ".expanded" ))** is the only line of code that you need here.

```js
      $(document).ready(function() { 
    
  var expanded = false;

  $( ".container ul li" ).click(function(e) {
            var li =$(this);
   if (expanded) {
                li.after($( ".expanded" ));
    $( ".expanded" ).slideUp("slow");
    expanded = false;
   }
   else {
                li.after($( ".expanded" ));
    $( ".expanded" ).slideDown("slow");
    expanded= true;
   }
  }); 
 });
```

```css
body, ul {   
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;  
   }
   .container {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
   }
   li {
    width: 23%;
    margin: 10px 1% 0 1%;
    float: left;
    list-style: none outside none;
   
   }
   li img {
    width: 100%;
   }
   
   .expanded {
    position: relative;   
    display: none;
    background: #ccc;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <ul>  
      <li>
       <a href="#"><img src="http://s13.postimg.org/8caamw1af/image4.jpg" /></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#"><img src="http://s13.postimg.org/8caamw1af/image4.jpg" /></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#"><img src="http://s13.postimg.org/8caamw1af/image4.jpg" /></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#"><img src="http://s13.postimg.org/8caamw1af/image4.jpg" /></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#"><img src="http://s13.postimg.org/8caamw1af/image4.jpg" /></a>
      </li>
     
     <li class="expanded">
     <div>abc</div>
     </li>
        
    </ul>
   </div>
```

Comment: No, not cloned, i just need insert after @puneet

Comment: $(this).insertAfter($('.container ul li #item-'+a)).slideDown(400); @puneet

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to find out if same element is clicked twice (if so, just slide div up), otherwise -> slide it up (close 'previous'), and then down (re-open). Since one div is in question, referencing 'previous' doesn't have too much sense, and, actually, i am not sure how this will work with mentioned ajax... However, credits to: **icktoofay** ([How to see if you're clicking the same element twice? Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688561/how-to-see-if-youre-clicking-the-same-element-twice-jquery)), here it is:
http://jsfiddle.net/3a7pjeb9/11/

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    var previousTarget = null;
    $(".container ul li").click(function(e) {

      if ($('.expanded').is(':visible') != true) {

        $(".expanded").slideDown("slow");
      } else {
        if (this === previousTarget) {
          $(".expanded").slideUp("slow");
        } else {

          $(".expanded").slideUp("slow");
          $(".expanded").slideDown("slow");
        }

      }
      previousTarget = this;

    });
  });
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3a7pjeb9/13/ actually i just need to insert the div 4th li, 8th li, 12th li, depend on the li stay in which row @nevermind

Comment: 'div 4th li, 8th li, 12th li' - what this means, sorry? The code/example from original question isn't close to this... however - for 'google images' functionality - you need just one thing -> get image src and show it in big 'expanded' div (i think you are over-complicating this). :)

Comment: yes, that was, but i just need insert after, i have push the content from ajax actually for this expanded div @nevermind

Answer (score 0):

Is this the result you wanted ? If no, let me know, I work to a project similar to yours.

http://jsfiddle.net/3a7pjeb9/14/

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

    var expanded = false;

    $( ".container ul li" ).click(function(e) {
        if (expanded) {
            $( ".expanded" ).slideUp("slow").children().remove();



            expanded = false;
        }
        else {
            $( ".expanded" ).slideDown("slow");
            $(this).clone().appendTo('.expanded');

            expanded= true;
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand the picture. You want when user click a image to slideDown a <div> that contains the respective image(or not) on it and for the rest of the images to go down too when that <div> slides down?

Comment: No, the go down only for the clicked, the rest still at beside them @eddnewgate